# How can I set a layer visible dynamically using Flex Viewer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

I have a set of layers in operationallayers tag in my Flex Code connected to ArcGIS Server 10, and I want to make them visible dynamically in a ComboBox Change Handler.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I remembered seeing something in the [esri resources gallery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/gallery.html)
However the format has changed a bit and the descriptions are not as complete.
I think it was on a third party sample site.
maybe it was this [Calhoun County site](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/16882-programmatically-turning-layers-off-on)